# What is the best way of passing user info/profile/context via web API service

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api

I am a newbie who is writting ASP.Net web API service for the very first time. The issue I am having is how to pass user information or different contexts via service request. For example I want to pass user context (i.e username, user preferences etc.) and lets say security context (i.e. api key, secret etc.) thru each service call. The options I found
1. using Query string
2. custom HTTP headers
3. overload authorization header to pass Jason object
4. cookie

I ditch the idea of using query string as it has 2k limitation, custom header could be ripped by proxy services, dont want to use cookie,creating a jason object of all the context and send it via auth header can work but seems like not a smart way. Any idea? what is the best way of passing those extra information.

I really appreciate if someone help me with some examples.